# Are these sets of ratios of polynomials countable or uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Are these sets countable or uncountable?

1. The set of all ratios of two polynomials of degree at most $3$ with integer coefficients.
2. The set of all ratios of polynomials with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** The set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable. Next show that "ratio" is just a fancy term for something defined by a pair of elements. Show that the product of two countable sets is countable, and conclude the final answer.

You can find threads on this very site about both the statements (polynomials with integer coefficients being countable; and the product of two countable sets is countable).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a bijection between the set of natural numbers and the set that you defined in `a`.

I would hint that there's coefficients for this polynomial $c_1,c_2,c_3$ which are all in the set of natural numbers and that if you look at the set of ordered tuples created with $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ you might be able to see how a bijection could be created. Then you might be able to use the fact that the product of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Z * Z is countable so all you need is to define a bijection from Q to Z * Z

we could consider the bijection:

f(p/q) = (p,q) with p and q both integers (q cannot be equal to 0)

thus f is at least an injection from Q to N*N (from which the case for q = 0  must be eliminated)

Now by combining this injection with another that goes from Z * Z to N (we know it exists since Z * Z is countable) we construct an injection from Q to N and thus Q is countable

Now the question you may want to ask is how does one show that Z * Z is countable?